# MySQL product extra's

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

I'm building a web application using a MySQL database. Users can order products but with these products there are a lot of extra features that can be added to the product the user wants. Example: user1 => order: product1 + extra 1,2,3. User2 => order: product1 + extra 1. User3 => order: product1 + no extras.

I'm currently struggling to get this in MySQL properly...

Any remarks or hints to get this done properly?

[image]

Comment: How are the extras related to the products? Can a product have any extra?

Comment: Some products can have extra's others can't and for those that can there are 6 possible extras

Comment: Will there always be only 6 extras and will there always be a "Have all or none" relationship?

Comment: the user has 6 possible extras but he can choose for only 1 or 2 or 3 or all 6 or none at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it future proof and to follow Boyce–Codd normal form (BCNF) I would place extras in a own table as you have done, then use a many-to-many table linking productID's to extraID's. That way if in the future if you want more extras or some products can have different extras there won't be a problem.

Then you can also make another many-to-many table connecting orderdetailID's with extraID's to know what has been added to each product.

Answer (score 0):

You could try joining between all the tables like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Order o LEFT JOIN Orderdetail od
ON o.orderID = od.oderID
LEFT JOIN products p
ON od.productID = p.productID
LEFT JOIN extra e
ON e.extraID = p.productsExtra
```

N.B. Your field productsExtra is smallint with size 10 while extraID is smallInt 5. You should reconsider if they share primar/foreign key relation.